# Лишний / в письме для восстановления пароля. Django

Tags: django, sendmail, sendmessage

Сделал шаблон письма с ссылкой на сайт и по итогу приходит вот такая вот ссылка
http://localhost:8000//reset....
Эти два / перед reset лишние, но я не знаю как их убрать. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает.
Шаблон сообщения:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col">
                <h3>Уважаемый {{user.username}}</h3><p>Кликните по ссылке ниже для того, чтобы сбросить пароль <br>
                    <a href="{{protocol}}://{{domain}}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}">ссылка</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>  
{% endblock content %}
```

В urls.py лишних / в начале не нашел
domain.name просто вырезает http://localhost:8000/ и остается reset/и т.д.

Comment: Значит у вас в переменной `domain` прописан лишний слеш, а откуда у вас переменная `domain` вообще взялась — это уж вам виднее

Comment: дополню, что `{% url .. %}` всегда возвращает относительный путь, т.е. начинается с `/`

Comment: ОКей, спасибо. Попробую найти домен